# program simulating keypress numbers 1 - 999

Tags: python, keyboard

so I have this program where what I want it to do is simulate keypress of numbers from 1 - 999 but it does not seem to work and it stopped working when it is supposed to type the number 10 and I am not sure how to fix it code:

```
    import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
import time
x = 0
time.sleep(1)

for write in range(1000):
    keyboard.press(str(write))
    keyboard.release(str(write))
    print(str(write))
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(0.005)
```

Comment: Looks to me like `keyboard.press()` is expecting a single character, there's no "10" key on a keyboard so you need to break it down into a key press for "1" and another for "0" if you want to type multi digit numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`press` and `release` only accept one character. Try changing it to `type`:

```py
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
import time
x = 0
time.sleep(1)

for write in range(1000):
    keyboard.type(str(write))  # Here, change it to .type() instead
    print(str(write))
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(0.005)
```

You can also use the [`pyautogui`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or the [`keyboard`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/README.md) module.

#### With pyautogui

```py
import pyautogui

# Your other stuff here

for i in range(1000):
     pyautogui.write(str(i))  # Write the number
```

#### With keyboard

```
import keyboard

# Your other stuff here

for i in range(1000):
     keyboard.write(str(i))  # Write the number
```